# Line Numbers in Listing Outside of Paragraph

Tags: listings

I use the listings package for code listings and I turned the line numbers on. But they appear left of the paragraph. I want them inside the paragraph. In the documentation it looks just right. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Test
\begin{lstlisting}
    test()
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

use

```
\lstset{numbers=left,xleftmargin=2em,frame=single,framexleftmargin=1.5em}
```

Comment: ok that helps, but I use frame=lines and the lines change too with this setting

Comment: I tried framexleftmargin=-1.5em but it ignores the minus

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: ah thanks, misunderstood the framexleftmargin